# how to send command to VT220 through telnet

Tags: ios, unix, networking, telnet

I want to make a emulator for accessing my server through telnet in my iPod, 
but there is very big problem arise.
i have able to make connection with telnet but not understand how to send command to unix server through telnet . Basely I am not able to understand the format in which data should be send to server.
I don't have any code for that.
Please give me some guidelines for this.

so far, My negotiation process is going as following :
Overall Negotiation

```
IAC DO AUTHENTICATION 
                        IAC WONT AUTHENTICATION

IAC WILL ENCRYPT    
                        IAC DONT ENCRYPT
IAC DO TERMINAL_TYPE
                        IAC WILL TERMINAL_TYPE
IAC DO TERMINAL_SPEED (32)
                        IAC WONT TERMINAL_SPEED
IAC DO X_DISPLAY_LOCATION (35)
                        IAC WONT X_DISPLAY_LOCATION
IAC DO NEW_ENVIRONMENT
                        IAC WILL NEW_ENVIRONMENT
IAC DO ENVIRON (36)
                        IAC WONT ENVIRON
IAC SB NEW_ENVIRONMENT 
SEND IAC SE
                        IAC SB NEW_ENVIRONMENT IS USERVAR
                        “KBDTYPE” VALUE “BRB” USERVAR “CODEPAGE”
                        VALUE “37” USERVAR “CHARSET” VALUE “697”
                        USERVAR “DEVNAME” VALUE “#DEVICE_NAME#”
                        IAC SE
IAC SB TERMINAL_TYPE 
SEND IAC SE
                        IAC SB TERMINAL_TYPE QUAL_IS “vt220” 
                        IAC SE 

IAC WILL SUPPRESS_GO_AHEAD
                        IAC DO SUPPRESS_GO_AHEAD
IAC DO ECHO (1)
                        IAC WONT ECHO
IAC DO LIMEMODE (34)
                        IAC WONT LIMEMODE
IAC DO NAWS (31)
                        IAC WILL NAWS 
                        IAC SB NAWS 0 80 0 24 IAC SE
IAC WILL STATUS
                        IAC DO STATUS
IAC DO REMOTE_FLOW_CONTROL (33)
                        IAC WONT REMOTE_FLOW_CONTROL
IAC WILL ECHO
                        IAC DO ECHO
IAC DO TIMING_MASK
                        IAC WONT TIMING_MASK
IAC DO TRANSMIT_BINARY
                        IAC WILL TRANSMIT_BINARY
```

Please review this process and suggest me the corrections if any.

Comment: What do you mean? How to send data to the server? Simply send the characters, there is no "format" (except for control characters like Control-H, that is). Or do you want to know how to interpret the VT220 escape sequences you receive?

Comment: i want to know is there any specified command format as such in TN5250 emulator consisting cursor position and other associated things.

Comment: Telnet is just a TCP connection on port 23 and you sen/receive a stream of bytes. VT220 is a common set of escape codes that are used for things like colour, cursor positioning etc. it expands on the earlier Vt-100 sequences http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/chapter2.html

Comment: @Paulw11 but what i am receiving as string of bytes just consisting of character on screen with no colour or cursor positioning etc.

Comment: Then maybe your `TERM` variable on the remote end isn't set correctly.

Comment: @DarkDust please suggest me how to set `TERM` variable on remote and who can set it, i just have an IP Address(Port : 23).
I have set the terminal-Type to VT220 at negotiation time.

Comment: You either simply type something like `export TERM=vt220` when you're connected, or you implement the [_Terminal-Type_ option as defined in RFC1091](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1091) to have that done automatically for you.

Comment: we have already set terminal-Type to VT220 at negotiation time from same RFC.

Comment: Enter `echo $TERM` to see whether the remote side really picked that information up. If not, force it by setting `export TERM=vt220` for debugging to receive escape sequences. But really, this conversation is drifting in the wrong direction and already is about a topic that is very different from your original question. If you want to find out what you're doing wrong, use a _real_ TELNET client and observe what it's sending with Wireshark or tcpdump, then check what you're doing and fix it.

Comment: we have done negotiation with VT220 , we have got the Login Screen it having just ASCII characters to display.

Comment: Yeah maybe because there simply is no need to send escape sequences at that point? Check with a _real_ TELNET client, use Wireshark to read the communication and adapt your own client so it acts the same. That's the last comment from me on this topic. Good luck.

Comment: You need to read the Telnet RFC - there is a negotiation phase by which your client (your app in this case) can identify what type of terminal it is. If you skip this then you get a plain TTY

Comment: @DarkDust and paulw11 , I am closer to solve my Problem but i have a question regarding this. 
Q:Do i need to send character to server as they a type and appear on screen?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question as this: *how are special keys like cursor keys sent and how do I interpret the stuff the server sent me?*

You want to read some documentations about [VT220 escape sequences](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/chapter2.html) (see also the complete [VT220 programmer reference manual](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/contents.html)). This is your "protocol" on top of telnet.

You may also want to read details about the [TELNET protocol](http://mars.netanya.ac.il/~unesco/cdrom/booklet/HTML/NETWORKING/node300.html) itself.